# Filling missing values in dataframe column Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My data is broken up into 4 columns and looks like:

```
State       Year        Month        Value
AK          2010         1             10
AK          2010         3             20
AK          2011         1             28
AK          2011         5             29
AK          2011         12            31
.
.
TX          2010         2             10
TX          2010         3             11
TX          2010         4             20
TX          2010         12            22
TX          2011         4             30
TX          2011         7             33
.
.
```

I want to fill the missing **Months** with repetitions of the previous **Values** of the same **Year** because they are just cumulative sums that I've added together.

The months **do not always begin back at Month 1** and **sometimes can be missing full years** so I need to address this.

Ie: TX can start at Month 4 in 2011 etc...

The desired output looks like:

```
State       Year        Month        Value
AK          2010         1             10
AK          2010         2             10
AK          2010         3             20
AK          2010         4             20
AK          2010         5             20
.
.
AK          2010         12            20
AK          2011         1             28
AK          2011         2             28
.
.
TX          2010         1             9
TX          2010         2             10
TX          2010         3             11
TX          2010         4             20
TX          2010         5             20
.
.
TX          2010         12            22
```

Comment: Do you need the same Year - Month span for each state? Or are they separate for each state?

Comment: Will every sequence begin with 1 always?

Comment: They differ from State to State (AK may start at 1980 but TX or LA can start in 1991) but I need each Year to span the full 12 months for every State.

Comment: Good question, @coldspeed. They do not begin at 1 always but I need them filled from the last month's value and automatically fill each from 1-12. I have changed my question to better address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html):

```
# convert Month to categorical with 1-12 range
df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df['Month'], categories=range(1, 13))

# groupby to give Cartesian product for categorical columns
df = df.groupby(['State', 'Year', 'Month']).first().reset_index()

# forward fill by group
df['Value'] = df.groupby('State')['Value'].ffill()
```

This solution assumes Dec-2010 data can spill over to null data for Jan-2011 for a particular state.

Comment: I actually have a strange nan issue. I've posted a screenshot above. Looks like it's not picking up previous years at times but it's because of what you had mentioned. Is there a way to spill over previous years?

Comment: @HelloToEarth, Unfortunately, I can't replicate without a [mcve]. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) if you need help with this (images / links don't help).